JPA OR query to search 2 fields for 1 value passed as parameter
I have a JPA method which has 2 arguments passed below:
orderRepository.findOrderByDigitalRecipientAccountIdOrSoldToAccountId(account.get().getId(), pageable);

Page<Order> findOrderByDigitalRecipientAccountIdOrSoldToAccountId(@Param("account_id") Long accountId, Pageable pageable);

I am making a JPA query that simply (without @Query annotation) needs to make a call that checks 2 fields in the orders table (digitalRecipientAccountId, soldToAccountId)
to check if either of these fields have a value that matches the id passed as argument1 , then return the orders associated.
I am not looking for a JPA query that is taking more than 2 arguments, then checks if the value of arg1 OR arg2 are present in 1 field in the table. This would not be ideal:
Page<Order> findOrderByDigitalRecipientAccountIdOrSoldToAccountId(Long digitalRecipientAccountId, Long soldToAccountId, Pageable pageable);

There should only be 1 value passed for accountId which is compared against 2 fields, digitalRecip.. OR soldToAccount..
If it is only possible to achieve this with @Query hard coding the query, please let me know.
Thank you!

Using the generic JPA methods (without a query) the only way is to pass the same id twice as method parameters. Like:
findOrderByDigitalRecipientAccountIdOrSoldToAccountId(id, id, pageable);

